# WCF transaction rollback

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, distributed-transactions

I have a composite WCF service. i.e. it calls 3 other WCF services -- i have control over all of these. I am trying to wrap all 3 into a transaction. However, it is unclear to me what to do in the case where call 1 and 2 succeed, and 3 fails.. I need 1 and 2 to be rolled back, which means i need some sort of callback for commit/abort on each operation of each of the 3 services. I can't find any documentation on how this would be done.. is this even possible?

Comment: This article may be of some assistance: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35087/Truly-Understanding-NET-Transactions-and-WCF-Imple

Comment: I read that and just re-read again.. Still doesn't answer my question.. Where is the rollback code? Maybe a specific example of my question; Service A: static int i = 1 at construction. Transaction operation sets i=2. If theres a rollback, set i back to 1. Service B: Same thing but throws an exception after i=2. Service AB calls A then B inside a transaction. What fires the rollback i=1 in service A and B? More specifically, if the rollback is real code, not just 'revert variables' but something more like fire another webservice that handles rollbacks where does that go?